# Model inheritance in App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to create 3 different models that have some common properties and methods, but are separate in the DB. I couldn't find any examples of inheriting from another model without using the `PolyModel` base class.

Is it safe to do the following?

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    common_prop = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def common_method(cls, a):
        ...

class SonModel1(BaseModel):
    private_prop = db.StringProperty()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use PolyModel? That's what it's for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Mainly for backwards compatibility reasons. From my understanding, `PolyModel` will store all the derived models in the same DB table. I need to keep the separate tables.

Comment: Thinking in terms of db tables is misleading you. There are absolutely no such things with the datastore.

Comment: If you just want to reuse property definitions for different models, then the code you provide is fine